# useEffect empty data after refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, use-effect

I am fetching games from API. I use useEffect to display data after I will come to page. It works. But if I refresh page I get two Arrays. The first is the array with my data, but second is Array with this code:

*Object { title: "Syntax Error", status: 400, cause: "Expecting a STRING as input, surround your input with quotes starting at 'undefined' expecting {'{', 'f', '(', '[', 'true', 't', 'false', 'null', 'n'" }*
​​

*cause: "Expecting a STRING as input, surround your input with quotes starting at 'undefined' expecting {'{', 'f', '(', '[', 'true', 't', 'false', 'null', 'n'"*

​​
*status: 400*

​​
*title: "Syntax Error"*

So the page shows second array, not first because it overwrites my data.
Maybe I am using useEffect wrong. I would really appreciate any help.

This is my code:

```
const [myData, setmyData] = useState("")
    const GameData = () => {
        const settings = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Client-ID': 'my_client-id',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer my_authorization',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(`fields summary,id,name,cover.*; where id = (${id});`)
        }
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await fetch('../api/example', settings);
            const data = await response.json();
            setmyData(data)
        }
        fetchData()
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!myData) {
            GameData()
        }
    }, [GameData]);
```

[image]

Comment: check the network tab, on both cases. Is the request the same for both cases? also `JSON.stringify()` expects object or array not string

Comment: try this
const [myData, setmyData] = useState({})

You try to assign an object to a string

Comment: @Sisir I see only one request so I think it's the same.

Comment: @Abregre It returns empty object without data.

Comment: The 400 error code, indicates that there is a problem with your request body. maybe you send a unique id and your backend expects otherwise? Have you tried remove the JSON.stringify at all?

Comment: You are right. I tried write id manually and now there is now error. I use useRouter, router.query to get id. I cant remove JSON.stringify because it will not return the data. How can I pass id with no error?